# Error! Template does not exist

Tags: python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

I have been trying to create an simple web application using django but keep getting the error as TemplateDoesNotExist

**my url**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from buisnesscard import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/', views.login, name='login'),
]
```

**my views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.loader import get_template


def login(request):
    return render(request, get_template('form.html'), {})
```

instead of using get_template i even tried

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'buisnesscard/templates/buisnesscard/form.html', {})
```

**Settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

tried changing the dir to

```
'DIRS' :[ 'buisnesscard/templates/buisnesscard']
```

my html files contains a simple static file and it gets the error as

```
form.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/
Django Version: 1.10b1
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
form.html
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10b1-py2.7.egg\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 25
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.9
Python Path:    
['E:\\Django files\\forms',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.10b1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 6 Jul 2016 10:57:11 +0530
```

currently running on python version 2.7

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, the template name should be a string

```
return render(request, 'buisnesscard/form.html', {})
```

The example tutorial may be of some help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render

Comment: Correcting that error still gives me the same TemplateDoesNotExist error!Help

Comment: Are you positive the file you've pointed Django to actually resides inside buisnesscard/templates/buisnesscard/form.html?

Comment: the templates folder should be lower case

Comment: Change `'buisnesscard/templates/buisnesscard/form.html'` to just `'buisnesscard/form.html'`. Sorry for the confusion